# ng click inside script type ng template is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to make a custom typehead Angular Bootstrap UI, here is my custom template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplateall.html">
       <a>
          <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
          <br>
          <small>Nama Lain:{{match.model.tag}}</small>
      </a>
</script>
```

So, with that code I would like to mention some result after user type some characters in an input field, here is the code for the input field:

```
<div class="wrp-search">
        <div class="labelsearch"><img src="images/bulb-black.png" alt=""/> Tulis Jenis Pemeriksaan</div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.nama" placeholder="Contoh: Diabetes" uib-typeahead="item as item.name for item in dataall | filter:{tag:$viewValue} | limitTo:10" typeahead-min-length="2" typeahead-template-url="customTemplateall.html">
        <input type="submit" class="btn-green" ng-click="cari()" />
</div>
```

So, I would like to have multiple search result, for example like: [1 MG Labs](https://www.1mglabs.com/)

So when the user clicked the typehead, it goes to the multiple result and when the user click "GO" then it directs to the result.

Is there anything that I must do?

Update:

Here is the scope in mycontroller:

```
$scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
        $scope.$item = $item;
        $scope.$model = $model;
        $scope.$label = $label;
            // alert($scope.$item.name);
            $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/api/v1/order/cart/add/byname',
              data: {
                name: $scope.$item.name
              }
            }).success(function(){
              // $window.location.href = 'order/pemeriksaan';
              $scope.cartget();
              $scope.nama.name = ""; //this is the code
            }).error(function(){
              alert("pencarian gagal");
            })
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function provided by the angular ui-bootstrap:

```
$scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
    //$scope.$item = $item;
    //$scope.$model = $model;
    //$scope.$label = $label;

};
```

This function will run whenever the user selects any option from the typeahead. So you can open a modal to display multiple results.

You can find this function under the typeahead settings heading here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Example:

```
$scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
    var id = $item.id;
    // This function opens a modal
    // You could also create an alert
    $scope.getMarketPlayerID(id);
    // This statement clears the input to blank
    $scope.selected = "";
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the wonderful reply.. I just wonder which scope that I must use for do that... in the docs it doesn't tell me the function of each $item, $model, $label, or $event... and would you mind to give me an example to only give alert for any thing that I have clicked?

Comment: Hi, the problem is solved, I just have to uncomment what you have done... I just want to know how to make the search form blank after the user click what he/she wants...

Comment: To make the input blank, just assign empty string to the input model. Use the scope of the controller in which all your logic is written. I have edited the answer and added an example.

Comment: Hi, I have followed your example, as you can see on my question, the ng-modal of the input is $parent.nama, so how I can assign the blank to it?

Comment: To make it clear, I have updated the question for your information

Comment: try adding $scope.nama = "";

Comment: Still no luck, is there anything that I can change?

Comment: try changing your ng-model value to this: ng-model="nama"

Comment: great, it is working as I expected, thank you so much Mohit Yadav